# include_once and include function return strange output

Tags: php, include

here is my code :

**abc.php**

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<4;$i++){
    echo include_once('text.php');
    echo include('text.php');
}

?>
```

**text.php**

```
Hello World
```

Returns output :

```
Hello World1Hello World11Hello World11Hello World1
```

What is `1` in above output ?

Comment: When you include a file, it's text contents are already echoed out, just remove the `echo`. According to the manual: `Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are all the iterations:

```
1) include_once: Hello World1 // include file echo automaticaly, and echo 1 (success)
   include: Hello World1 // include file echo automaticaly, and echo 1 (success)
2) include_once: 1 // included already only success...
   include: Hello World1
3) include_once: 1 // included already only success...
   include: Hello World1
4) include_once: 1 // included already only success...
   include: Hello World1
```

Output: `Hello World1Hello World11Hello World11Hello World1`.

As metndioned in comments, include automaticaly echo the code, so `echo include` echo the file, and echo the return value of include function :). Which is true = 1.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 is the  return value of the include_once call. If you include a file that does not exist with include_once, the return result will be false. 
If you try to include that same file again with include_once the return value will be true.

Comment: 1 is also return for include() function too

Comment: Sure, I forgot to mention that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the **echo** from in front of **include** & **include_once**.

**This is Wrong**

<strike>echo include_once('text.php');</strike>

<strike>echo include('text.php');</strike>

Placing **echo** in front these functions will only return whether or not the file was found and included. 
[jacek-kowalewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1125465/jacek-kowalewski) pointed this out earlier. Although saying that **include** automatically **echoes** could be somewhat confusing. **include()** injects the code into the main file wherever the function is called. The contents of the included file could be just text OR it could be more php code. If it is more code it will not echo anything unless the echo function is invoked.

---

I don't understand using **include** and **include_once** for the same file?
- **text.php**

Using **include_once()** AND **include()** together creates a situation where one cancels the the other. **include_once('text.php')** means that **text.php** can ***only be included one time in the main script***. Include on the other hand will allow text.php to included as many times as the function is called. But in this case **text.php** cannot be called multiple time because include_once() has already set the rule for only once.
[See Includes Canceling](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=inlcude_once-include-require#exp)

If there is a string of text that you want to output two times consecutively to the webpage then you should place the **echo** command inside of the **text.php** file:

```
echo 'My String of Text';

echo 'My Second String of Text';
```

Then place **include_once** into your main script:

```
include_once('text.php');
```

You may want to rewrite your script like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
echo 'Text '.$i.'<br />';
 $i =$i+1;
echo 'Text '.$i.'<br />';
}
```

Your output will be:

```
Text 0
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
Text 5
```